# Magento 2 "Add to Cart" button appear on category pages for "Out of Stock" products

Tags: magento2, category, catalog, inventory, magento2.3.5-p1

Magento 2.3.5
Add to cart button will not show on the category page. It shows instead of "out of stock"

Also, there is an issue on Magento GitHub - https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/26942

How to remove the "add to cart" button from the category page when the product is out of stock?